# How to find and query a specific build in Jenkins using the Python Jenkins API

Tags: python, json, jenkins, querying, jenkins-api

We have a Jenkins job that runs builds using specific parameters.
Two of these parameters are important for me: the machine that the build is being deployed on, and the version number of the package that is deployed.

> https://jenkinsurl/job/folder_level1/job/folder_level2/job/folder_level3/job_id/

Here is a sample of json output of the url:

> https://jenkinsurl/job/folder_level1/job/folder_level2/job/folder_level3/job_id/api/json

```
{"actions":[{"parameters":[{"name":"lab_name","value":"labA"},{"name":"version_no","value":"1.1"}]}
```

Using the Jenkins REST API or the Python Jenkins wrapper, how would I search for the job if I know the folder_level1 and would like to match the lab name to a job in folder_level3 to finally get the version from that URL?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use the /api/xml format:

```
https://jenkinsurl/job/folder_level1/api/xml
```

which returns the `action` XML node which can be queried via XPath:

- https://jenkinsurl/job/folder_level1/api/xml?xpath=//action&wrapper=root

Take the matching name from there to search for the data in question:

- builtOn - the machine that the build is being deployed on
- number - the version number of the package that is deployed

Using an XPath for each, along with a wrapper node for grouping, such as the following for builtOn:

```
https://jenkinsurl/job/folder_level1/api/xml?depth=3&xpath=//fullDisplayName[contains(text(),'foo')]/following-sibling::builtOn&wrapper=builtOn_results
```

and another for version:

```
https://jenkinsurl/job/folder_level1/api/xml?depth=3&xpath=//fullDisplayName[contains(text(),'foo')]/following-sibling::number&wrapper=version_results
```

**References**

- [Jenkins Wiki: Remote Access API](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Remote+access+API)
- [Taming the Jenkins JSON API with Depth and "Tree" | CloudBees](https://www.cloudbees.com/blog/taming-jenkins-json-api-depth-and-tree)
- [python-jenkins API(pdf)](https://media.readthedocs.org/pdf/python-jenkins/latest/python-jenkins.pdf)
- [xml.tree.elementtree: Supported XPath Syntax](https://docs.python.org/2/library/xml.etree.elementtree.html#supported-xpath-syntax)

Comment: Solved it using a version of your solution but did not remember to post the answer earlier. Thank you!